# ConstraintLayout Visibility Show not working after taking picture with camera

Tags: xamarin.android, imageview, android-camera, visibility, android-constraintlayout

I need to take a picture and show it in `SelectedImageView` which is located inside `SelectedImageConstraintLayout`. It works perfectly when I open the gallery and select a picture, but it is not working for the camera. `SelectedImageConstraintLayout` is not visible at all.

```
void OpenCamera()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    var filename = new File(this.ViewModel.IssuePhotosDirPath,
                            this.ViewModel.TEMP_PHOTO_FILENAME);
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(filename));
    StartActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_CAMERA_ID);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        var issuePhotoFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(this.ViewModel.IssuePhotosDirPath,
                                                        this.ViewModel.TEMP_PHOTO_FILENAME);

        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case OPEN_CAMERA_ID:
                ShowIssueImage(issuePhotoFilename);
                break;
            case OPEN_GALLERY_ID:
                //do something to save the image in temp file before showing it
                ShowIssueImage(issuePhotoFilename);
                break;
        }
    }
}

void ShowIssueImage(string fileName)
{
     if (SelectedImageViewWidth > 0 && SelectedImageViewHeight > 0)
     {
          var bitmap = fileName.ResizeAndRotate(SelectedImageViewWidth, SelectedImageViewHeight);
          SelectedImageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
          bitmap = null;
     }
     else
     {  
          SelectedImageView.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName));
     }

     AddImageConstraintLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
     SelectedImageConstraintLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
}

void RemoveIssueImage()
{
     SelectedImageConstraintLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
     AddImageConstraintLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

     var issuePhotoFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(this.ViewModel.IssuePhotosDirPath, this.ViewModel.TEMP_PHOTO_FILENAME);
     System.IO.File.Delete(issuePhotoFilename);
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using `ViewState.Invisible` instead of `ViewStates.Gone` resolve it. Although I don't know why `ViewState.Gone` works for picking image from gallery.

```
void RemoveIssueImage()
{
     //Here, I need to change it from ViewStates.Gone to ViewStates.Invisible
     SelectedImageConstraintLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

     AddImageConstraintLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

     var issuePhotoFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(this.ViewModel.IssuePhotosDirPath, this.ViewModel.TEMP_PHOTO_FILENAME);
     System.IO.File.Delete(issuePhotoFilename);
}
```

and later in `ShowIssueImage` function, change `AddImageConstraintLayout.Visibility` to `ViewStates.Invisible`.